Issues with Updating Widget Timeline Based on SwiftData/CoreData Changes in WatchOS App
I tried looking everywhere online and asked AI, but it seems none of the solutions resolved my issue. I am using CoreData or SwiftData with CloudKit to fetch data from the database. I created a simple app to practice communication between iOS/iPadOS and the Apple Watch app, along with a widget.
I was able to send data to my Apple Watch app without any problems, and everything runs smoothly. When I add, update, or remove people via the iOS/iPad app, my Watch app updates perfectly. However, there’s one issue with the widget: it won’t update unless I open the app on the Watch, at which point the widget finally updates.
Is there a way to trigger the widget’s timeline to update when there are any changes to SwiftData or CoreData? Also, updating the widget every 5 minutes is fine with me, but unfortunately, the widget doesn’t update at all every 5 minutes.
I’ve included the full widget code below—could you help identify any issues? Do you have any suggestions for making the timeline call if SwiftData has been updated? I tried using @Query, but I understand that @Query doesn’t work in widgets, if I’m correct.
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import CoreData
import CloudKit
import UserNotifications

@Model
final class Person {
    var uid: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String?
    var birthday: Date?
    var height: Double?
    var weight: Int?

    init(uid: String, name: String, birthday: Date, height: Double, weight: Int) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    }
}
func setupModelContainer() -> ModelContainer {
    let config = ModelConfiguration()
    
    #if DEBUG
    autoreleasepool {
        let descriptor = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: config.url)
        let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.myapp.Watch-Connection-Data")
        
        descriptor.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
        descriptor.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false
        descriptor.isReadOnly = true

        if let model = NSManagedObjectModel.makeManagedObjectModel(for: [Person.self]) {
            let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Watch Connection Data", managedObjectModel: model)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [descriptor]
            
            // Load the persistent stores
            container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
                if let error = error {
                    fatalError("Failed to load persistent store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Persistent store loaded successfully: \(storeDescription)")
                }
            }
            
            // Remove the store after schema creation
            if let store = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first {
                do {
                    try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store)
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failed to remove persistent store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endif

    return try! ModelContainer(for: Person.self, configurations: config)
}

@MainActor // Ensure this is run on the main actor
func fetchPeopleFromContainer(completion: @escaping ([Person]) -> Void) {
    let container = setupModelContainer()
    let context = container.mainContext
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Person>()
    
    do {
        let people = try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        for x in people {
            print("Person name: \(x.name)")
        }
        completion(people)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching people: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion([])
    }
}

struct PeopleWidgetEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let people: [Person]
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> PeopleWidgetEntry {
        PeopleWidgetEntry(date: Date(), people: [])
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (PeopleWidgetEntry) -> Void) {
        fetchPeopleData { people in
            let entry = PeopleWidgetEntry(date: Date(), people: people)
            completion(entry)
        }
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<PeopleWidgetEntry>) -> Void) {
        fetchPeopleData { people in
            let entry = PeopleWidgetEntry(date: Date(), people: people)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5))) // 5-minute interval
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPeopleData(completion: @escaping ([Person]) -> Void) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            fetchPeopleFromContainer { people in
                completion(people)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Watch_WidgetEntryView: View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        switch widgetFamily {
        case .accessoryInline:
            Watch_Inline_View(personData: entry.people)
        case .accessoryCorner:
            Watch_Corner_View(personData: entry.people)
        case .accessoryCircular:
            Watch_Circular_View(personData: entry.people)
        case .accessoryRectangular:
            Watch_Rectangular_View(personData: entry.people)
        default:
            Text("Not available at this time: \(widgetFamily)")
        }
    }
}

